# search through regex pattern in a file

Tags: shell, awk, sed, tcl

I have a file with data in below format

```
abc {u_bit_top/connect_down/u_FDIO[6]/u_latch}
ghi {u_bit_top/seq_connect/p_REDEIO[9]/ff_latch
def {u_bit_top/connect_up/shift_reg[7]
```

I want to search for pattern `*bit_top*FDIO*` and `*bit_top*REDEIO*`in the file in each line and delete the complete line if pattern is found.
I want output as

```
def {u_bit_top/connect_up/shift_reg[7]
```

I did using sed like `sed "/bit_top/d;/FDIO/d;/REDEIO/d;"` but this deletes the line having ***bit_top*** and ***FDIO*** and ***REDEIO*** separately.
How I can search for above pattern and delete the line containing it.
Shell or TCL anything will be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've been close! ;)

```
sed '/bit_top.*FDIO/d' input
```

Just input a regex to sed that matches what you want...

Answer (score 4):

Since you tagged [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl)

```
set fh [open "filename"]
set contents [split [read -nonewline $fh] \n]
close $fh
set filtered [lsearch -inline -not -regexp $contents {bit_top.*(FDIO|REDEIO)}]
```

results in

```
def {u_bit_top/connect_up/shift_reg[7]
```

[`lsearch` documentation](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lsearch.htm).

---

But really all you need for this is [grep](/questions/tagged/grep)

```bash
grep -Ev 'bit_top.*(FDIO|REDEIO)' filename
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E '/bit_top.*(REDE|FD)IO/d' input_file
def {u_bit_top/connect_up/shift_reg[7]
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
abc {u_bit_top/connect_down/u_FDIO[6]/u_latch}
ghi {u_bit_top/seq_connect/p_REDEIO[9]/ff_latch
def {u_bit_top/connect_up/shift_reg[7]
```

then

```
awk '/bit_top/&&(/FDIO/||/REDEIO/){next}{print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
def {u_bit_top/connect_up/shift_reg[7]
```

Explanation: if lines contain `bit_top` AND (`FDIO` OR `REDEIO`) then go to `next` line i.e. skip it. If that did not happen line is just `print`ed.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 1):

With a small change you can implement the compound pattern (eg, `*bit_top*FDIO*`) in `sed`.

A couple variations on OP's current `sed`:

```
# daisy-chain the 2 requirements:

$ sed "/bit_top.*FDIO/d;/bit_top.*REDEIO/d" file
def {u_bit_top/connect_up/shift_reg[7]

# enable "-E"xtended regex support:

$ sed -E "/bit_top.*(FDIO|REDEIO)/d" file
def {u_bit_top/connect_up/shift_reg[7]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file line by line and perform not operation on your regex pattern.

```
set fp [open "input.txt" r]
while { [gets $fp data] >= 0 } {

    if {![regexp {bit_top.*(FDIO|REDEIO)} $data match]}
    {puts $match}

}
close $fp
```